# apt-get update 404 on trusty

Tags: 14.04, apt

Does anyone know why these are 404ing? At those paths, there are `{path}.gz` and `{path}.bz2` which I can wget fine.

```
vagrant@mt-repl:/tmp$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is my `sources.list`:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
#

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
```

It is a vagrant box built using https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64

Comment: I guess you have a problem in your `sources.list`..please edit your question and add the entries of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: What wound up being the fix here?  Did you find resolution?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm behind a proxy. I had configured apt-get to use the proxy, but I had a trailing slash in the proxy url.

For some things, such as getting the list of sources, this worked fine. But for downloading the actual artifacts, this caused an issue.

The solution was to remove the trailing slash from the proxy url.

Comment: I guess it ended up with a `//` in the URL somewhere :)